# Broken font rendering in GNOME default apps

Tags: 20.04, gnome, graphics, fonts

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 on a 2010 Mac Pro, and have had successful results for about a year until now.  After booting this morning, I attempted to open GNOME Terminal.  It appears that the font rendering is broken.  Only parts of the words are rendering.  The best example of this can be seen in the Settings app:

[image: a screenshot of Settings]

Random letters are bolded and the longest words rendered are cut to four letters long.  I've already tried running `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`, and it doesn't fix the problem.  I've also tested changing the font, which also doesn't help.  Rebooting does not fix this, and it appears to be duplicated across accounts.  This glitch only appears in certain areas - for example, the top bar does not display the issue, and <s>nor do any third-party apps</s> *I've discovered that it may be a GTK issue, because Brasero and a few other native apps have the same issue*.

Help on this issue is greatly appreciated, considering it makes all GNOME default apps unusable.

Comment: @ubfan1 Thanks so much!  I searched for the issue, and didn't find anything.  However, running the commands from that question worked.